# Is it possible to add search/share contracts on my windows phone apps?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am developing windows phone 8 apps using VS2012 with Windows phone SDK8.0.
I am looking for the solution to add search/share contracts in my application.

Answer (score 0):

Search contracts doesn't exist on Windows Phone.

Share contracts doesn't exist either, but depending on what you want to share, there are extensibility points: for example, if you want to allow photo sharing, you can register your app as an image sharer, see [Extending the Windows Phone Pictures Hub](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Extending_the_Windows_Phone_Pictures_Hub).

Comment: I want to share some text content via e-mail. Can I?

Comment: You need to use the ShareStatusTask http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394027(v=vs.105).aspx